# getting this error while enhancing using Datanucleus. any idea

Tags: datanucleus

I am trying to enhance a class (class is generated during run time with annotations). And getting this error. DN says it is null pointer. 
any idea?

```
22:03:36,816 (pool-7-thread-1) DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Registering class "test.TESTClass" as not having MetaData.
22:03:36,817 (pool-7-thread-1) ERROR [DataNucleus.Enhancer] - Error thrown enhancing with ASMClassEnhancer
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.jdo.JDOMethodAdapter.visitFieldInsn(JDOMethodAdapter.java:103)
    at org.datanucleus.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1333)
    at org.datanucleus.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:953)
    at org.datanucleus.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:684)
    at org.datanucleus.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:521)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.jdo.JDOClassEnhancer.enhance(JDOClassEnhancer.java:427)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhanceClass(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:927)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:534)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOEnhancer.enhance(JDOEnhancer.java:125)
    at com.xxxx.MYClassLoader.findClass(MYAClassLoader.java:615)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please post your class.

When strange things like this happen, I `clean` my project. (i.e. delete all built classes. In Eclipse: `Project > Clean...`)

And make sure the annotations you are using are based on the correct path. Use `JDO` annotations and not `Datanucleus`'s (i.e. Use `javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable` and not `org.datanucleus.api.jpa.annotations.PersistenceCapable`, although I'm not sure if this is even possible as the compiler would complain as it is for me)

Comment: tried all those things. and one of the misleading is class doesn't have metadata. but usually DN builds it based on annotations if .jdo files are not existing. and which is working okay for other classes.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, hopefully it will get you through

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thanks for reply. I use jdo annotations. As I mentioned, I enhance several classes in my app. I am getting only problem with this class(diff is this particular class is generated during run time) So, I made additional coding to handle classloading for this class. but getting stuck at this null error as DN doesn't give any more details.